# How do you hold an element from one recurse until the next recurse in an in-order traversal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am working on verifying a BST. If you are to do an in-order traversal of a tree, it will output the values in sorted order. Further, if you compare the previous element with the current element, you can verify it's sorting:

Where A is any sorted list:

[image: equation for sorted list]

Instead of in-order traversing the values and storing them into an array to validate (O(n) space complexity), I wanted to hold the previous element and check it on the next recurse. For example:

[image: Binary tree]

In an in-order traversal, I would get 1 3 4 6 7 8 10 13 14. Which is in order, adheres to the equation I wrote, and is a binary tree. The problem I am having is writing (and understanding) recursion that will allow me to hold a previous value. I would like to get to 1 (base case) and hold it until the next element, which is 3. I confirm that 3 is bigger than 1, then 3 becomes the previous and I hold it until the next element. The next element is 4, I confirm 4 is bigger than 3, then I hold 4 until the next element... and so on.

Here is my code:

```
void InOrder(Root* root)
{
    Root* previous;

    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    else
    {
        previous = root;

        InOrder(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " " << previous->data << endl;
        InOrder(root->right);
    }
}
```

It's quite obvious that this code only does an in-order traversal. I have searched and read around and I can't find anything clear for this. How do I store a value from one recursion cycle until the next recursion cycle?

Comment: Here's a hint:  If you pass a minimum and maximum value to each node you can check if the tree is a BST.  For the first node, pass in the minimum integer and the maximum integer.  As you traverse down, change the min/max as appropriate as you recurse.

Comment: Also, your InOrder function doesn't need to keep the previous or to print it out.

Comment: Another way to do it is pass a reference to a variable that holds the last checked value.

Comment: I would go with @AnonMail's solution since all you need is to verify you've got a valid BST.

Comment: is there a reason you are trying to verify if the tree is a BST this way? there is a much more simple and concise way of verifying if the tree is a BST or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
bool InOrder(Root* root, int *min, int *max)
{
  return root == NULL ||
         (InOrder(root->left, min, &root->data) &&
          (min == NULL || *min < root->data) &&
          (max == NULL || root->data < *max) &&
          InOrder(root->right, &root->data, max));
}

bool InOrder(Root *root)
{
  InOrder(root, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Basically, you pass two additional arguments and check that current value lies within the range (min, max).
On left recursion, you change your max, on right recursion -- your min.

I'm passing pointers so that when it's NULL, there is no need to check.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are passing a variable, by reference, called `prev`. I have initialized `prev` with INT_MIN from the `climits` header file, or you could initialize it with a value smaller than all your BST values.

```
void InOrder(struct node* root, int& prev)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return ;

    else
    {
        InOrder(root->left,prev);
        if(prev<root->data)
        {
            prev = root->data;
            //printf("prev is %d\n",prev);
        }
        cout << root->data << endl;
        InOrder(root->right,prev);
    }
}
```

You can change your code accordingly from here.
Also you can check out this following [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/)
Hope you got the idea.